# jQuery ui selectable: function does not react to deselection when there is only one element selected

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-selectable

The following is a code for jQuery ui´s selectable plugin. The code allows me to select more than one selectable object with the mouse without the lasso and without the keyboard. The console.log message does come up in firebug when I select. It also comes up when I have more than one selectable selected and deselect some of them.

The problem is, when there is only one element selected and I deselect it, nothing happens. I need the console.log message to come up also in that situation.

Any help appreciated

```
<style>
    #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
    #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
    #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
            e.metaKey = true;
        }).selectable({
            stop: function() {
                var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
                $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                    var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                    result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );

                                    console.log("test")
                            });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<p id="feedback">
    <span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>.
</p>

<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your console.log function fires only for each of the selected items because the selector there is ".ui-selected". When you deselect the last one, there aren't any selected so the function doesn't fire at all.

You can bind another function for each of the non-selected items, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
        e.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();

            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
                 console.log("selected");
            });

            $( ".ui-selectee", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
                console.log("not selected");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You can make it more dynamic by firing a function for each item that you just selected or unselected. For this you can use the selected and unselected events of selectable. This fires at the same time as stop and fires for each item that you just selected or unselected, depending on which one you use. So for example:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
        e.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            // fires at stop
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        },
        selected: function(event, obj) {
            // this function will fire for each item that was just selected
            // obj is the selected object
            console.log("selected");
            console.log(obj);

            // Not sure if this bit will work, could try this instead of obj
            var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index(obj);
            $('#result').append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );

        },
        unselected: function(event, obj) {
            // this function will fire for each item that was just deselected
            // obj is the unselected object

            console.log("deselected");
            console.log(obj);

            // Not sure if this bit will work
            var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index(obj);
            $('#result #" + ( index + 1 )').remove();
        }
    });
});
```